# UI bootstrap: highlighting matching chars while typing more than one word

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive of UI Bootstrap. I have a text input with a typeahead like this:

```
<h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
<pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address as (address.formatted_address + ' ' + address.place_id) for address in getLocation($viewValue)" class="form-control">
```

If user types more words separated by spaces (e.g. *mona utah*) I would like to highlight in the proposed resulset all words matching user keywords (i.e. both *mona* and *utah*). 
Default behaviour of this directive seems not providing this feature.

[Here there is a little plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnt3sZDJ3mCgLK8KAIOt?p=preview) describing my example. As you can see, if I type *mona utah*, the text in the resulset is not higlighted.

Comment: You are going to have to rewrite a portion of the directive. It might be as straight-forward as changing the output of typeaheadHighlight filter but outside of that I think you are going to have a lot of work on your hands.

Comment: Oh : ( isn't there any high level solution that does not imply the rewrite of the directive?

Comment: I don't think so. [Here is the line where it is highlighting the match](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L407). It just highlights whatever is queried and matches.